# Using Javascript to check a box in Gmail

Tags: javascript

I'm working on creating a shortkey to add a label to an email in gmail.

```
<div class="J-LC" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false" id=":4x3" title="Positive Responses" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
  <div class="J-LC-Jz" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
    <div class="J-LC-Jo J-J5-Ji" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
    Positive Responses
  </div>
</div>
```

When I simulate checking the box in Gmail and watch the DOM, this happens:

```
<div class="J-LC J-Ks-KO J-LC-JR-Jp" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="true" id=":4x3" title="Positive Responses" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
  <div class="J-LC-Jz" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
    <div class="J-LC-Jo J-J5-Ji" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
    Positive Responses
  </div>
</div>
```

Two things happen:

1.) `aria-checked` becomes `True`

2.) `class` is updated

I tried this: `document.querySelector('div[title="Positive Responses"]').setAttribute("aria-checked", true)`

And it changed the value to be True, but when looking at Gmail the box wasn't actually checked. Is the only way to do this is hard code in the update of `class`?

Comment: all you're doing is fiddling with the DOM - the equivalent of spraying some graffitti on a wall. unless gmail has some code observing the dom, it'd never see your changes.

Comment: So aria isn't at all used for anything but data. I'd assume that the `id` of the div has something to do with the checkmark before I would aria. `ARIA stands for Accessible Rich Internet Applications.`

Comment: You would have to set the box BEFORE the DOM loads. Otherwise, if GMail has no DOM manipulation API - chances are you wont be able to change it after load as you have no way to set up a GMail observer to make the change to the GMail DOM. You can update the classes all day long, but without a way to tell GMail that an actual DOM change request is being made, you are just changing classes after the fact. In short, if a SaaS application has no DOM manipulation API - changing the DOM post load is often not possible.

Comment: @Marc - So there's no way to check a box once the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Normally, yes. If you were writing the application you could add listeners to elements on load. You are not writing Google, so all you can do is access DOM elements - not change them dynamically without an API. Using something like jQuerys .change() method you could normally attach the change handler to a parent element and this will allow you to dynamically look for changes to its children, but since you did not write GMail, you cannot add functionality to its internals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a different DOM than yours.

**For me this worked -**

Find the ID of the div with `role=checkbox`

Then `document.getElementById(ID).click()`

Comment: I just tried that. `document.getElementById(':579')` returns `<div role="menuitemcheckbox"...>` but when I do `.click()` on that `undefined` is returned.

Comment: That's why I said getting different DOM. Which browser?